# Invoke-Command fails to create new VMs

Tags: powershell, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I created this script to create multiple VM's remotely on the Hyper-V server, however, it doesn't seem to create the VM's. I can create one directly on the Hyper-V server using the given parameters while using Enter-PSSession, but not via invoke-command? (there are no error messages, it just prints a blank line and goes back to the prompt)

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][int]$newvmcount #require number of temp vm's to create
)
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {foreach ($vmnumber in $newvmcount){New-VM -Name "Windows10TMP$vmnumber" -BootDevice NetworkAdapter -Generation 2 -SwitchName LAN -MemoryStartupBytes 1gb -NewVHDPath "F:\hypervvirtualmachines\Windows10TMP$vmnumber.vhdx" -NewVHDSizeBytes 127gb -verbose}} -ComputerName hypervserver -ArgumentList $newvmcount
```

Comment: try passing $newvmcount into the invoke with the arguments parameter.  Inside the script block you'll need a new param declaration as well.  seems redundant i know but it's how it works.  If that works I'll type up a formal answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the $using scope modifier. It would look like this`$using:newvmcount` which let's you use the variable defined outside of the invoke-command

Answer (score 2):

Apply [How to pass arguments for remote commands](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/12/29/how-to-pass-arguments-for-remote-commands/):

Either declare the parameter(s) at the beginning of your scriptblock:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
  param($newvmcount)
  foreach ($vmnumber in $newvmcount) {
      New-VM -Name "Windows10TMP$vmnumber" `
        -BootDevice NetworkAdapter -Generation 2 `
        -SwitchName LAN -MemoryStartupBytes 1gb `
        -NewVHDPath "F:\hypervvirtualmachines\Windows10TMP$vmnumber.vhdx" `
        -NewVHDSizeBytes 127gb -verbose
  }
} -ComputerName hypervserver -ArgumentList $newvmcount
```

or access argument(s) using the [automatic variable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6) `$args`.

BTW, I can't understand the `foreach` loop as `[int]$newvmcount` does not seem to be a collection…

Comment: dude...  as you can see I'm already waiting for feedback from OP as to if this is the solution.

Comment: I changed the loop to a for loop, based on your feedback about the loop, however, I went with SteamerJ's solution, as it was a bit simpler, and I believe I've used "$using:" in the past.

Comment: both solutions work, it just depends on what you like. @JosefZ solution is a bit more readable in terms of you understand where the scope is coming from, whereas $using requires understanding of how that scope modifier works which someone not familiar with powershell will have to infer from it 'just working.' I was in this same situation literally a few days ago when I learned about this. I had trouble with this method and ended up learning about $using.